# how to set default value for formset django

Tags: python, django

i'm trying to build an app which contains django inline formset , but default values only show for the first form!?
this is my model

```
class Main(models.Model):
     admin = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     A= models.ManyToManyField(Item,through='Child')
     B = models.IntegerField()

class Child(models.Model):
     main = models.ForeignKey(Main,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     item = models.ForeignKey(Item,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)
```

my views.py

```
class CreateMainInlineFormset(LoginRequiredMixin,SuccessMessageMixin,CreateView):
    model = Main
    form_class = MainForm
    template_name = 'main/create.html'
    def get_context_data(self, *args,**kwargs):
        data = super().get_context_data(*args,**kwargs)
        if self.request.POST:
            data['items'] = ChildInlineFormSet(self.request.POST)
            data['items'].full_clean()
        else:
            data['items'] = ChildInlineFormSet()
        return data

    def form_valid(self, form):
        context = self.get_context_data()
        items = context['items']

        with transaction.atomic():
            self.object = form.save(commit=False)
            form.instance.admin = self.request.user
            if items.is_valid() and form.is_valid() and items.cleaned_data!={}:
                items.instance = self.object
                form.save(commit=True)
                items.save()
            else:
                return render(self.request,self.template_name,context)
    
        return super().form_valid(form)
    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy('maininfo:list-item')
```

my forms.py

```
class ParentForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
       model = Main
       fields = [
           '__all__'
       ]

class ChildForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
       model = Child
       fields = [
           '__all__'
       ]

 ChildInlineFormSet= inlineformset_factory(
    Main,Child,form=ChildForm,fields=(
       'item','quantity'),
       extra=1
    )
```

i have to display `quantity` default value for all of the forms , but it only display for the first form , the rest will be null

Comment: Are `ChildInlineFormSet` in views.py and `ItemInlineFormSet` in forms.py supposed to be the same thing?

Comment: yes , sorry for missing it , updated

Comment: @HunarMohammed: Have you been able to solve the problem?

Comment: @LovePutin no, i changed to modelformset_factory